# Unknown source option not visible

Tags: android

I have attached two screen link here. I just wanted to know that one app is showing the "Install Unknown apps" in App information. For another, it is not showing at all. As both are installed on the same device.

Please find the links here:

[First App Description image](https://ibb.co/r6k787w)

[Second App Description image](https://ibb.co/wpNjSH8)

Comment: Because in Oreo (8.0), the universal unknown sources option has been removed and instead, every app needs individual special access to install apps from unknown sources. Now, comes the point why just some apps because the option is only visible in those applications which the android firmware detects as possible sources, maybe which contains download managers or possibly third party links. See [this](https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/63/18/63660253607284/0/sideload-apps-android-8-0-higher-now-unknown-sources-is-gone.w1456.jpg) image which lists chrome as a possible source and the reason for it.

Comment: Also, you can read [this](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/sideload-apps-android-8-0-higher-now-unknown-sources-is-gone-0184399/) link to understand more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of 1 app is published on googleplay and the other app is also not and its unknown in this way for the device